# Perl Regex Match string until whitespace

Tags: regex, string, perl

I have a simple email validation regex to create.

For the moment I have this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

print "mail from: ";
my $mail_from = lc(<STDIN>);

if ($mail_from =~ /(([^@]+)@(.+))/) {
  $mail_from = $1; 
  print $mail_from;
  print "250 OK\n";
}
else{
  print "550 ERROR \n";
}
```

But the problem is that I can enter various character after the .com like
me@gmail.com blabla

How can I match the string until the first whitespace ?

Regards,

Comment: You can get various character *before* the @, too.

Comment: [This has been answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address?lq=1) Also, see [Email::Valid](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Email-Valid-1.192/lib/Email/Valid.pm)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps try a pattern like this:

```
/(([^@]+)@(\S+))/
```

`\S` will match any non-whitespace character.

Answer (score 1):

The `.` in your regex matches any and all characters, including whitespace. Try `\S` instead, which matches any non-whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Use `\S` to match non-whitespace, and you can slightly simplify the previous term by using a reluctant (a.k.a. non-greedy) quantifier:

```
/((.*?)@(\S+))/
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely you don't need *three* captures in your regex?

You probably want to avoid angle brackets before and after the `@` as well.

I suggest at least this

```
/([^<>@\s]+\@[^<>@\s]+)/
```